# Make an eval button (code)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck on this, some advice on what I'm missing would be really appreciated. Basically I have the `runcode` button execute the code, but I don't think I'm doing it right.

code= code+ dropped.item.attr("rcode");
   (whatever was put onto the drop zone, show circle/change color etc)

Thanks a lot in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/avmbrnw7/42/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .block {
      width: 200px;
      background-color: yellow;
      margin: 10px;
      cursor: move;
    }
    .container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 250px;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .output {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    .circle {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function addItem() {
      alert("Hire security team!");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').show();" >Show Circle </div>
    <div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').css({'background-color':'blue'})"> Make the circle blue </div>
    <div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').fadeOut(500);">Fade out Circle </div>
    <div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').slideUp(500);">Slide Up</div>
    <br>
    <div class= "container" ></div>
    <br>
    <button id="runcodebtn" >Run Code</button>
    </br></br>
    <div class= "output" ></div>
    <div class= "circle" ></div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script>
  $(".block").draggable({helper: 'clone'});

  $(".container").droppable ({
      accept: ".block",
      drop:function(event,ui) {
          var dropped_item= $(ui.draggable)();
          $(this).append(dropped_item);
          code= code+ dropped.item.attr("rcode");
      }
  });

  $("#runcodebtn").click(function() {
      eval(code);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of minor fixes done mentioned below:

use `var dropped_item= $(ui.draggable);` instead of `var dropped_item= $(ui.draggable)();`

and `code = code + dropped_item.attr("rcode");` instead of `code = code + dropped.item.attr("rcode");`

and initilized variable `code`

```js
function addItem() {
   alert("Hire security team!");
  }
$(document).ready(function(){
var code = "";
 $(".block").draggable({helper: 'clone'});
 $(".container").droppable ({
   accept: ".block",
   drop:function(event,ui){
     var dropped_item= $(ui.draggable);      // from $(ui.draggable).clone();
     $(this).append(dropped_item);
     code = code + dropped_item.attr("rcode");
   }
  });
 $("#runcodebtn").click(function(){
  eval(code);
 });
  });
```

```css
.block {
 width:200px;
 background-color: yellow;
 margin:10px;
 cursor: move;
}
.container {
 width:300px;
 height:250px;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
.output {
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 background-color:lightgreen;
}
.circle {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:100px;
 background-color:red;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src= "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<center>
<div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').show();" >Show Circle </div>
<div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').css({'background-color':'blue'});"> Make the circle blue </div>
<div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').fadeOut(500);">Fade out Circle </div>
<div class= "block" rcode= "$('.circle').slideUp(500);">Slide Up</div>
<br>
<div class= "container" ></div>
<br>
<button id="runcodebtn" >Run Code</button>
</br></br>
<div class= "output" ></div>
<div class= "circle" ></div>
</center>
 <input type="text" value="Testbutton"/>
 <input type="button" value="Add item" onclick="addItem();"/>
</center>
```